# Mongoose findOne() on collections's document having nested property in array resolves even when the data doesn't match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose I have a user with few tokens in database. One of those tokens have access: 'unauth', and others as : 'auth' in the db. I am trying to get access via one of the token, the token that I am using...has access as 'unauth' in db. So ideally User info should not be retrieved using that specific token. How come User.findOne() still gets resolved ??

User's snapshot

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a56798ebf68677d469c8226"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-01-10T20:43:30.895Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-01-10T20:37:34.081Z"),
"email" : "test@testing.com",
"password" : "somepwd",
"tokens" : [ 
    {
        "access" : "unauth",
        "token" : "dfdgdgfgdfgdfgdfgfdgfddfg",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a56798ebf68677d469c8227")
    }, 
    {
        "access" : "auth",
        "token" : "gjhjjjhhhjhhjjhjhjhjjjjjjjjjghfgh",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a567a0ebf68677d469c8229")
    }
],
"__v" : 4
}


User.findOne({
 '_id': '5a56798ebf68677d469c8226',
 'tokens.access': 'auth',
 'tokens.token': 'dfdgdgfgdfgdfgdfgfdgfddfg'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I managed to do it...., the reason it was showing result was because Mongodb finds every element with any of those property in the array.  For anyone who stumbles on it...as referenced in docs to search on a nested array element the syntax is => ("arrayName":{ $elemMatch: {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}, "key":"value"});